# Как реализовать скачивание нескольких наложенных картинок одной

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Добрый день, у меня такой вопрос: есть 2 контейнера, в один я могу загрузить картинку (через AJAX), а во второй (он поверх него) я загружаю уже готовые изображения (Шляпы, очки и все в таком духе), беда в том что они не являются одним элементом, как мне реализовать скачивание всех этих элементов одной картинкой

Благодарю за ответы)

Comment: Нужно слить картинки в одну. Либо в браузере (на canvas) либо на сервере (зависит от платформы).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работает это через элемент `canvas`. Создаётся элемент canvas1 создаём второй канвас, вставляем картинки в них, вставляем `canvas2`  в `canvas1` получаем картинку в base64:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw = canvas.width;
var ch = canvas.height;

var canvas2=document.getElementById("canvas2");
var ctx2=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw2=canvas.width;
var ch2=canvas.height;


var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/77231305/454817.jpg";

img2 = new Image();
img2.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img2.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/77231305/images.jpg";
img2.onload = start2;

function start(){
  canvas.width=img.width;
  canvas.height=img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
}

function start2(){
  canvas2.width=img2.width;
  canvas2.height=img2.height;
  ctx2.drawImage(img2,0,0);
  var dataURL= watermarkedDataURL(canvas,canvas2);
}

function watermarkedDataURL(canvas,canvas2){
  var tempCanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
  var tempCtx=tempCanvas.getContext('2d');
  var cw,ch;
  cw=tempCanvas.width=canvas.width;
  ch=tempCanvas.height=canvas.height;
  tempCtx.drawImage(canvas,0,0);
  tempCtx.drawImage(canvas2,150,150);
  // just testing by adding tempCanvas to document
  document.body.appendChild(tempCanvas);
  return(tempCanvas.toDataURL());
  }
```

```css
body{ background-color: #e1e1e1; padding:20px;}
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width=50 height=50></canvas>
```

Comment: Определился бы, "canvas", "канвас" или "конвас")